# Retrieving Data From SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a user login application . I want to show account information of a user when he logs in  in textviews of a  layout . Here is the image of a layout .[image]

Here is my code for getting data of a user when he logs in :

```
public Cursor getUserData(String username){
    Cursor UserDataCursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + USER_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + 
            USER_NAME + "='" + username+"'", null);
    return UserDataCursor;
```

Here is the code for retrieving data with that class :

```
                String email2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
                String name2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                String pass2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pass"));
                String gender2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("gender"));
                String date2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                String country2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("country"));
                String reg2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("reg"));
                data+=email2+" "+name2+" "+pass2+" "+gender2+" "+date2+" "+country2+" "+reg2+"\n" ;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
```

It's giving a null pointer exception . What's the problem here ? How can i fix it ?

Comment: I used Cursor cursor = dbopen.getUserData(username); at top of the given code .

Comment: It could be any number of things. You should post the error you receive in Logcat to help us figure out where to look.

Comment: what is cursor? please post that code also. cursor.getString("email"); did you try just this?

Comment: It's showing this error : 

01-17 21:59:59.766: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-17 21:59:59.786: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 21:59:59.786: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.fahimahmed.app.login.ViewDataActivity$1.onClick(ViewDataActivity.java:70)

Comment: @thinksteep , Cursor cursor = dbopen.getUserData(username);

Comment: what is line 70 in ViewDataActivity class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making things much harder for yourself by not using the database adapter pattern.

Take a look here for an example of how to set up more abstraction and error handling for your database:
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954

It is difficult to verify your code, since it is data-dependent.  Your column names could be wrong (or one could be missing).  Your data type could be wrong.  You might be getting a cursor back with NO rows, which you need to check for.

BTW, are you doing cursor.moveToFirst() before starting?

Also, we don't know what's on line 70, where the error occurred, because line numbers are lost in the posting.